# стиль для активного таба(пункта) меню

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, menu, index

Есть боковое меню, по клику на пункт которого загружается контент в div через ajax. Не могу понять, как подсвечивать активный пункт меню. Пытался всякими способами это сделать, но без результатно. У меня deadline :(( Пожалуйста, помогите.. Код приведен.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu a').click(function () {
        
        $('.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu a span').removeClass('active');
        let n =$('.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu a').index(this);
        $('.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu a span').addClass('active');

    });
    
    $(".middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu a").click(function(){
        
        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: $(this).attr('data_target'),
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $(".middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_content").html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
    
   });
```

```css
   
.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
 height: 500px;
 margin: 100px 0 0 0;
 user-select: none;
}

.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section_text {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu">
                            <a class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section"
                                data_target="content/1.html">
                                <img src="img/icons/002.png" alt="">
                                <span
                                    class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section_text">
                                    test1
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section"
                                data_target="/content/2.html">
                                <img src="img/icons/001.png" alt="">
                                <span
                                    class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section_text">
                                    test2
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section"
                                data_target="content/3.html">
                                <img src="img/icons/004.png" alt="">
                                <span
                                    class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section_text">
                                    test3
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section"
                                data_target="content/4.html">
                                <img src="img/icons/0036.png" alt="">
                                <span
                                    class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section_text">
                                    test4
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section"
                                data_target="content/5.html">
                                <img src="img/icons/005.png" alt="">
                                <span
                                    class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section_text">
                                    test5
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section"
                                data_target="content/6.html">
                                <img src="img/icons/006.png" alt="">
                                <span
                                    class="middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu_section_text">
                                    test6
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

Comment: в css сюда забыл добавить класс active - .active {
     color: #B72A20;
    }

Comment: Зачем вы делаете название классов такой длины? Это же невозможно прочесть

Comment: Просто у меня методика такая - задавать двревовидное название. Прошу прощения. На будущее учту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант JavaScript

```js
const navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation')
navigation.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const mains = document.querySelectorAll('.main')
  const target = e.target
  Array.from(mains).forEach(main => {
    main.classList.remove('active')
  })
  target.classList.add('active')
})
```

```css
.active { background-color: red; color: white; }
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="main">Меню 1</div>
  <div class="main">Меню 2</div>
  <div class="main">Меню 3</div>
</div>
```

Вариант jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navigation').on('click', 'a', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      return;
    }
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
a {display: block;}
.active {background-color: red; color: white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <a class="main">Меню 1</a>
  <a class="main">Меню 2</a>
  <a class="main">Меню 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: сделал по аналогии - не работает. Может дело во вложенных тегах span, внутри тега a?

Comment: const navigation = document.querySelector('.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu a')
navigation.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const mains = document.querySelectorAll('.middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu a>span')
  const target = e.target
  Array.from(mains).forEach(main => {
    main.classList.remove('active')
  })
  target.classList.add('active')
})

Comment: второй вариант работает) но есть маленький момент... когда кликаешь чуть ниже текста пункта меню, то стиль active не применяется, а контент загружается.

Comment: слева от  каждого пункта меню есть картинка. Если кликать на них, но стиль тоже не меняется, а контент так же загружается.

Comment: да, верно, по тегу а

Comment: Хотя вот.. загрузка страницы у меня происходит вот так - middle_content_servicesdescriptions_content_descriptionandmenu_menu a

Comment: Не помогло. Все равно спасибо за помощь!